# SQL join with group by

Tags: sql, join

I'm still very new to joins and find them a bit confusing.

I have this query which uses a group by statement so that I get a list of unique t_id's

```
$list = mysql_query("SELECT t_id FROM table WHERE id='$id'  GROUP BY t_id ORDER BY date DESC ");
```

What I need to do though is get information from a separate table say table_2 based on this t_id. In table_2 the t_id only appears once so that makes things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$list = mysql_query("SELECT table.t_id, table2.linked_info FROM table LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.t_id = table.t_id WHERE table.t_id='$id'  GROUP BY t_id ORDER BY date DESC ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the query like this

```
SELECT t1.t_id, t1.date, t2.* FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.t_id = t2.t_id WHERE id='$id' ORDER BY date DESC
```

In this I believe `id` and `t_id` are different columns. If not correct the column name in where condition.